# Контейнеры неодинаково выровнены в рядах

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всех приветствую. В HTML-файле есть два ряда "преимуществ". Каждый ряд выровнен с помощью `display: flex`, а текст выровнен по центру. Но почему-то в каждом ряду `div`-ы выровнены по-своему, неодинаково. Хотел бы знать, в чём моя ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap">
    <title>Web-page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="advantages">
        <div class="advantages__first-line">
            <div class="advantages__experience">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/sand-watch.png" alt="sand-watch">
                <h2>Опыт</h2>
                <p>За 5 лет работы мы открыли мир йоги для более чем 1620 туристов</p>
            </div>

            <div class="advantages__services">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/castle.png" alt="castle">
                <h2>С нами спокойно</h2>
                <p>Русскоговорящее сопровождение – инструктор и переводчик будет с вами в течении всего тура</p>
            </div>

            <div class="advantages__professionalism">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/suitcase.png" alt="suitcase">
                <h2>Мы - профессионалы</h2>
                <p>Мы — самая большая компания в России, которая занимается исключительно йога-турами</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="advantages__second-line">
            <div class="advantages__profit">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/money-box.png" alt="sand-watch">
                <h2>С нами выгодно</h2>
                <p>Наш принцип – делать цены на йога-туры доступными для всех</p>
            </div>

            <div class="advantages__safety">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/protection.png" alt="castle">
                <h2>С нами безопасно</h2>
                <p>Вы получаете весь пакет официальных туристических документов</p>
            </div>

            <div class="advantages__convenience">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/plane.png" alt="suitcase">
                <h2>С нами удобно</h2>
                <p>Мы поможем забронировать авиа-билеты и оформить визу</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>

.advantages__first-line, .advantages__second-line {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-align: center;
}
.advantages__first-line h2, .advantages__second-line h2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.advantages__first-line p, .advantages__second-line p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Вы не указываете максимальную ширину данных контейнеров. И не делаете их одинаковыми. В результате контент внутри расширяет их до необходимого размера. Добавьте данным контейнерам `flex:1` общим классом например (в коде ниже добавлен `item`)

```css
.advantages__first-line, .advantages__second-line {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-align: center;
}
.advantages__first-line h2, .advantages__second-line h2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.advantages__first-line p, .advantages__second-line p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="advantages">
        <div class="advantages__first-line">
            <div class="advantages__experience item">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/sand-watch.png" alt="sand-watch">
                <h2>Опыт</h2>
                <p>За 5 лет работы мы открыли мир йоги для более чем 1620 туристов</p>
            </div>

            <div class="advantages__services item">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/castle.png" alt="castle">
                <h2>С нами спокойно</h2>
                <p>Русскоговорящее сопровождение – инструктор и переводчик будет с вами в течении всего тура</p>
            </div>

            <div class="advantages__professionalism item">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/suitcase.png" alt="suitcase">
                <h2>Мы - профессионалы</h2>
                <p>Мы — самая большая компания в России, которая занимается исключительно йога-турами</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="advantages__second-line">
            <div class="advantages__profit item">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/money-box.png" alt="sand-watch">
                <h2>С нами выгодно</h2>
                <p>Наш принцип – делать цены на йога-туры доступными для всех</p>
            </div>

            <div class="advantages__safety item">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/protection.png" alt="castle">
                <h2>С нами безопасно</h2>
                <p>Вы получаете весь пакет официальных туристических документов</p>
            </div>

            <div class="advantages__convenience item">
                <img src="../Creating sites/Yoga/images/plane.png" alt="suitcase">
                <h2>С нами удобно</h2>
                <p>Мы поможем забронировать авиа-билеты и оформить визу</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Если, вдруг, нужна будет поддержка IE11, то flex: 1 не будет достаточно...